# Callback to parent thread from child thread

Tags: java

I've got a parent thread. It's job is to queue request and init child thread. Child thread is supposed to get data from web service and callback to parent thread. Parent thread process data and start another child thread. The problem is that everything which is inside callback method is handled by the child thread not the parent thread. Is there a way to handle callback by parent thread? In other words the child thread finishes right after calling the callback method without processing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some design for that, but for starters I don't see the point of a child thread if the main thread won't do anything but wait for the child to complete. If, on the other hand, the main thread must serve further incoming requests, then it can't also serve the callbacks from child threads. You'll have to rethink that. One idea is for one thread to collect requests and push them to a queue. Child threads push their events to the same queue and there is a separate thread that processes events from the queue -- both the requests and responses from child threads.

If such a thing sounds good to you, then by all means use the `ExecutorService` to handle the queuing of jobs.

Comment: To check if I understood:
Threads:
Main - interacts with a user -> 
Service - queues request and start ->
Processor - handle request(get data from web service) ->
Viewer - show data on the screen

Do I have to have so many threads or it can be done simpler?

Comment: Do you mean that you actually have a GUI thread and want to offload the long operation (WS call) to a non-GUI thread? Is that all you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. All I want to know is that, when I successfully get data from WS with some thread do I have to create new thread to display data or can I call my parent thread to do that. I don't want WS thread to process displaying data.

Comment: It would have been much easier if you said so right in the question. This subject has already been covered many times over here on SO and elsewhere. The only class you need is `SwingWorker`. You'll see, it's quite simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

As Marko mentioned you can use ExecutorService which have Future reference there you can return result of running job to its parent thread.